# Show that $x^2-\frac{2}{x} < 3$ for all $x$ between $1$ and $2$ without graphing?

Tags: calculus, inequality

How do I show that $$x^2-\frac{2}{x} <3$$ for all $x$ between $1$ and $2$, without looking at a graph? I am open to algebraic and calculus related answers.

Comment: @user No I mean <, but forgot to say between 1 and 2 exclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the given interval $[1,2]$ the function $x^2$ is strictly increasing, and the  function $2/x$ is strictly decreasing so their difference is strictly increasing. So the maximum value is attained at $x=2$ which is 3.

Comment: +1 for showing the function is increasing without computing the derivative (even though the OP said calculus was OK)..

Answer (score 0):

Now

$1<x<2$ implies that $1<x^{2}<4$ therefore $0<x^{2} -x<2$ hence

$-2<x^{2} -x-2<0$ but $2<x+1<3$

Hence   $(x+1)(x^{2} -x -2)<0$

thus $x^{3} -2<3x$ ,

hence  $x^{2} -2/x <3$.

Comment: I can't figure out why this was voted down.

Comment: Its a good solution!! Its a great solution. I don't even know how someone can come up with this. I am impressed!

Comment: He went backwards most likely first.

Comment: $x^2-\frac{2}{x}<3$ gives $x^3-2<3x$ if $x>0$ which it is... Then $x^3-3x-2<0$ Then factor the left hand side...

Comment: Bit confused as to why I was voted down. The other solution is obviously a lot neater, but this also works. Maybe I've just got haters.

Comment: I am too confused about downvoting your correct answer.  +1 for your answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but the approach is wrong on several counts. You don't subtract inequalities. You don't multiply inequalities unless everything is positive, or you could have sign reversals. Check the steps, you have made all these errors.

Comment: All of the assumptions that were made were assumed because they were true. You seem to be disagreeing with a hypothetically wrong answer.